# Objective C: Why is this code leaking?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm trying to implement a method similar to what [mytunescontroller](http://code.google.com/p/mytunescontroller/source/browse/trunk/PreferencesController.m?r=15) uses to check if it has been added to the user's login items. This code compiles without warnings but if I run the leaks performance tool I get the following leaks:

```
Leaked Object  #    Address         Size   Responsible Library  Responsible Frame
NSURL          7    < multiple >    448    LaunchServices       LSSharedFileListItemGetFSRef
NSCFString     6    < multiple >    432    LaunchServices       LSSharedFileListItemGetFSRef
```

Here is the culprit:

```
- (BOOL)isAppStartingOnLogin 
{
    LSSharedFileListRef loginListRef = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (loginListRef) {
        NSArray *loginItemsArray = (NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginListRef, NULL);
        NSURL *itemURL;
        for (id itemRef in loginItemsArray) {           
            if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve((LSSharedFileListItemRef)itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef *) &itemURL, NULL) == noErr) {
                if ([[itemURL path] hasPrefix:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]) {
                    [loginItemsArray release];
                    [itemURL release];
                    CFRelease(loginListRef);
                    return YES;
                 }
             }
        }
    [itemURL release];
    [loginItemsArray release];
    CFRelease(loginListRef);

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: If you hit that `return YES` in the middle of the for loop, you're going to leak the array and ref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LSSharedFileListItemResolve()` returns an owned object in the third parameter. This can be verified by reading the header. As a result, you need to release `itemURL`.

Comment: If this specific to the function or is it "mandated" a convention that items "returned-by-pointer" have their ref increased?

Comment: It's specific to this function, though it can be generally expected from CoreFoundation-level APIs because autorelease only exists at the obj-c level.

Comment: I tried releasing itemURL but I still get the leaks. I have updated my code to reflect the changes.

Comment: You're only releasing it if your test succeeds. So any URL that *doesn't* have your prefix will get leaked.